# Flutter web - mixed texts reverse order on mobile browsers

Tags: flutter

I recently upgraded (flutter version,dart,packages) a flutter web project that has been running for about 2 years.
Since then, when I run the app on desktop browser all the textfields look fine.
For example, a phone number text field is displayed "054-12345678".
However, when I view it from a browser in my mobile (or other mobiles, iOS or Android) this same text is displayed as "12345678-054".
The same for dates, for example on desktop web it shows "08/03/2011" (correct) and on mobile browsers "2011/03/08".
The same for numbers, on desktop browser 0.02 is displayed as 02.0 on mobile browser.

The widget for the phone number and date is a simple Text(value ?? '').
The whole page is wrapped with a Directionality widget with TextDirection.rtl.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0GCC.png)

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

I tried wrapping the text widget with a Directionality widget with direction rtl but that did not work.
I tried using useMaterial3: false on my theme constructor but that didn't work.
I tried updating all my packages.
Couldn't find anything that fixed it.

Comment: I stumbled upon this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74906055/flutter-web-app-keeps-italicizing-on-mobile-browser?rq=2 which solved the issue for me. Using flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what solved it for me:
Using flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit instead of flutter build web.
Followed the thread I linked in my comment.
This is from Flutter docs:
Choose the auto option (default) if you are optimizing for download size on mobile browsers and optimizing for performance on desktop browsers.

Choose the html option if you are optimizing download size over performance on both desktop and mobile browsers.

Choose the canvaskit option if you are prioritizing performance and pixel-perfect consistency on both desktop and mobile browsers.